# How to pass an object from Corba Client to Corba Server

Tags: java, corba

Using Java as a programming language , i have this question regards how to send an object from Corba client to Corba server noting that i am using POA and the following idl file :-

```
// BackupServer.idl

#ifndef BackupServer_idl
#define BackupServer_idl

interface BackupDaemon;
#include "BackupExceptions.idl"
typedef sequence<BackupDaemon> BackupDaemonList;

interface BackupDaemon {
   attribute string backupDaemonUser;
   attribute string backupDaemonIP;
   attribute string backupDaemonHostName;
   attribute string backupDaemonBackupType;
   attribute string backupDaemonType;
   attribute string backupDaemonTime;
   attribute string backupDaemonPath;
   attribute boolean backupDaemonScheduled;
   attribute long backupDaemonPort;
   attribute string backupDaemonMacAddress;
   typedef sequence<string> BackupPathesStrings;
   boolean startBackup(
      in BackupPathesStrings backupPathes,
      in string backupDaemonMacAddress );
   void deleteBackup(
      in string backupPathes,
      in string backupDaemonMacAddress ) raises (BackupPathNotFoundException);
};

interface BackupServer {
   boolean registerBackupDaemon( in BackupDaemon bd )
      raises (InvalidBackupDaemonException);
   boolean unRegisterBackupDaemon(in string backupDaemonMacAddress)
      raises (InvalidBackupDaemonException);
   BackupDaemonList getBackupDeamons();
};
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If there any similar example , i will be interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only "true" object sent on the wire with CORBA is [ValueType](http://www.ciaranmchale.com/corba-explained-simply/more-details-on-idl.html#toc47) otherwise "references" may be exchanged and more [simple structured raw data as "struct" and "union"](http://www.ciaranmchale.com/corba-explained-simply/core-concepts-and-terminology.html#toc13).

Migrate a CORBA server from one location to another isn't trivial and not directly feasible but may be achieved with a complex deployment.